# Call C# dll with javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, dll, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Before I called a function in C# DLL using ActiveX, javascript on FireFox browser, but Ver Firefox newest no support ActiveX and I want dev a plugin support for some browser (Chrome, Firefox, ...). 
I hope everyone can help me find some solution to call DLL form native URL on client folder using javascript.

Comment: Create a web api with the function you want to call and use it in your extension.

Comment: You can use nativeMessaging API, see the documentation. You'll have to write a mediator utility though.

Comment: Thank every one
I'm trying and researching